# Is there a way to find who I sent an email to, after deleting the email in windows live mail from the trash folder, on windows 7?

Tags: email, data-recovery, email-client, windows-live-mail

I've sent an email with sensitive information, with Windows Live Mail, then put it in the trash folder of the software, then emptied the trash folder. The person on the other end never got the email. Is there an outgoing mail history somewhere on my computer, where I could check who I actually sent it to? I'm using Windows 7. I also have avast free installed, could there be a log of outgoing email scans?

Answer (score 0):

If you were using the web based client then Avast! won't have even noticed you were sending an email. Besides that, the outgoing mail history *is* the sent folder. If you've deleted it from there then you've effectively deleted the history.

If you were using a mail client on your computer, then you may be able to check the web client to see if the email is still on the server.

You could try contacting the Windows Live support team, but due to privacy considerations they may not be able to retrieve (or even see) any details about what you send or who it was sent to.

Comment: Isnt there a log somewhere of uotgoing communications, or smtp, in the registry, firewall, event log,somewhere?